# How to parse the above JSON and group them

Tags: jquery

I have JSON as follows

```
var json =
{
    "Qty1": {
        "values": [
            "Apple",
            "Mango"
        ],
        "name": "Qty2"
    },
    "Qty3": {
        "values": [
            "Banana",
            "Flower"
        ],
        "name": "Qty1"
    }
};
```

In the above JSON **Qty 1** refers to **Item 1** and **Qty 3** refers to Item 3 and so on --

How to parse this above JSON and display as follows

```
Item 1  : Apple , Mango 

Item 3 :  Banana , Flower
```

I have started as shown in this fiddle , but no clue on how to proceed ??

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/80/

```
var json =
{
    "Qty1": {
        "values": [
            "Apple",
            "Mango"
        ],
        "name": "Qty2"
    },
    "Qty3": {
        "values": [
            "Banana",
            "Flower"
        ],
        "name": "Qty1"
    }
};

var length = 3 ;

for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    alert(json[i].Qty[i].values);
}
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for (var qty in json) {
    var number = qty.match(/\d+/g);
    if (number.length) {
        number = number[0];
        console.log("Item " + number + ":" + json[qty].values.join(","));
    }
}
```

Log output:

```
Item 1:Apple,Mango
Item 3:Banana,Flower
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/81/